# Use NTILE function over a rolling window in BigQuery (rolling binning / rolling quantile)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple table with Time column (1 minute frequency) and another column of float value, let's call it column A.
My goal is to create a query in BigQuery that does the following:

For each row, look at the window of the preceding 24 hours and the following 24 hours, and get the relevant "bucket number" (as in `NTILE(5)` func) for the specific row which is the center of the window.

I'm trying to achieve a "rolling binning" - kind of similar to "rolling quantile" (as in pandas [Rolling Quantile)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.quantile.html) but with the bin number. I can do it quite simply in python with `pd.DataFrame.rolling.apply` and a custom function for binning and return a value, but I want to do it using BigQuery.

I'm having trouble combining both NTILE function and a rolling window.

I was able to create a rolling window (referred to as [Analytic function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) in the docs) and perform a simple aggregation such as average by using

```
SELECT Time, AVG(A)
OVER (ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(Time) ASC RANGE BETWEEN 86400 PRECEDING AND 86400 FOLLOWING) as rolling_avg_24_hours_each_side
FROM `my_project.my_table`
```

(86400 comes from 3600 seconds in a hour * 24 hours. Is there an alternative to the use of magic numbers?)

using `NTILE(5)` function over my entire table is quite easy, but I can't use it in my rolling window.

As the docs of [Numbering functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions) states, using a `window_frame_clause` is not allowed, therefore I can't use the `RANGE...` statement combined with `NTILE`.

So my main question is how to combine `NTILE` function with a rolling window, or are there other solutions to achieve "rolling binning" with a rolling window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this in BigQuery as far as I know.  The following method is not simple but it might work in your case.  Start by bringing together the rows that you need for each window:

```
select t.time, t.a, array_agg(t2.a) as window_a
from `my_project.my_table` t join
     `my_project.my_table` t2
     on t2.time >= date_add(t.time, interval -24 hour) and
        t2.time < date_add(t.time, interval 24 hour)
group by t.time, t.a;
```

Then calculate the the tile manually:

```
with t as (
      select t.time, t.a, array_agg(t2.a) as window_a
      from `my_project.my_table` t join
           `my_project.my_table` t2
           on t2.time >= datetime_add(t.time, interval -24 hour) and
              t2.time < datetime_add(t.time, interval 24 hour)
      group by t.time, t.a
     )
select t.*,
       (select ceiling(min(case when t.a = a2 then seqnum end) * 5.0 / max(cnt))
        from (select a2,
                     row_number() over (order by a2) as seqnum,
                     count(*) over () as cnt
              from unnest(t.window_a) a2
             ) w
       ) as rolling_tile
from t;
```

Comment: This snippet returns an error of "SELECT list expression references table alias a2 which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

Comment: However, the trick for combining a rolling window as array helps a lot! I managed to perform NTILE directly (without calculating the tile manually) by performing ```select t.time, t.a, a2 as value, NTILE(5) OVER (PARTITION BY t.time ORDER BY a2) as bin,
from t
CROSS JOIN unnest(t.window_a) a2 )```

and then use another select with distinct to get what I want. Do you want to edit your answer, or should I post another answer by myself with a credit?

Comment: Thank you, that works. I also added my own answer below which is using NTILE over the window you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) works, and by using his rolling window trick I managed to apply `NTILE` function directly instead of calculating it "manually" as suggested.

The first part remains the same, just creating the window.
Next, we can apply `NTILE` function over a `CROSS JOIN` between the tables:

```
select t.time, t.a, a2 as value, NTILE(5) OVER (PARTITION BY t.time ORDER BY a2) as bin, from t CROSS JOIN unnest(t.window_a) a2
```

the result is a table with some duplicate rows. For my needs I could just use `Min(bin)` and `DISTINCT` eliminate duplicates.

My full query:

```
with t as (
      select t.time, t.a, array_agg(t2.a) as window_a
      from `my_project.my_table` t join
           `my_project.my_table` t2
           on t2.time >= datetime_add(t.time, interval -24 hour) and
              t2.time < datetime_add(t.time, interval 24 hour)
      group by t.time, t.a
     )
select distinct time, Min(bin) from (select t.time, t.a, a2 as value, NTILE(5) OVER (PARTITION BY t.time ORDER BY a2) as bin, from t CROSS JOIN unnest(t.window_a) a2)
```